# DBT: Invalid incremental strategy provided: append on Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am getting the following error

```
Invalid incremental strategy provided: append
    Expected one of: 'merge', 'delete+insert'
```

with:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental'
    , incremental_strategy='append'
  )
}}
```

Please advise

Comment: If your data is append-only, either of those other strategies should work? What is wrong with them?

Answer (score -1):

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='uniqueCol'
    )
}}
```

Use incremental with unique_key, as name suggests it must be unique